# Pass by parameter a class with type assertion - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, factory, type-assertion

I'm simulating a multiple inheritance in typescript by this way:

```
export const FileManager = superClass => class extends superClass {
    //...
}

export declare abstract class Model<T extends Model<T>>{
//...
}
```

I tried the following and then it says that FileManager was expecting 1 parameter instead of 2.

```
export class Order extends FileManager(Model<Order>)){
//...
}
```

So I changed the FileManager definition to:

```
export const FileManager = (superClass,t) => class extends superClass<t> {
    //...
}
```

But then I get this error:

> [ts] Value of type 'typeof Model' is not callable. Did you mean to
>   include 'new'?

It was working well before I needed to declare the Type Assertion to model class (its neccesary, I cant remove it). 
I think the problem is the way I  receive the 'typeof' as parameter and how to instantiate dynamically.

Im really stuck, I will be very grateful to any help

Comment: The `T` in `Model` is it always the same as the derived class ? What do you need it for ? Are you sure polymorphic `this`  would not be a better fit ? Getting the mixin to work we can do, getting it to work with a generic class we can work around some limitations and we can do it. But the part that has the class referencing the class itself in it's extends expression clause is an issue I have not been able to figure out.

Comment: But why try to figure it out? When placing a language decoration facade (typescript) on top of a built-in language facade (Class) one must expect that strange inconsistencies will occur. The object hierarchy is interesting too. The `Filemanager` methods are accessed directly by the `Order`? I bet not.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Surprisingly yes! Order can access both attributes and methods as if their were own. The reason I decided to do this is that I found that there is no easy alternative to multiple inheritance that let you use base and super method (unlike mixins). I unsderstand that its prone to errors, but im trying my best

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Im using a library to implement typescript + sequelize and it defines a generic model in order to extend from it your classes and be able to use the ORM annotations

Comment: JavaScript is not a multiple inheritance language...you are attempting to work around the design of the language. You should concentrate on using the language the way it is designed to be used. Just because you can put a Kludge together doesn't mean you should. I know you can access them through the inheritance chain - that was not my point. The point was that your inheritance hierarchy is a kludge.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Its a total valid composition in Typescript. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4890 Here is one of typescript architects debating about it and after that he implemented an utility for that. My concern is how typescript interpret a type assertion parameter